# What are valid page names in Next.js? And how does it distinguish between pages and static resources?

Tags: next.js

I'm new to Next.js and am trying to get my head around client side and server side routing and what files need to be made available to download when Next.js is configured to use server-side rendering.

When I do a production build of a Next.js project, a `.next` directory is created (details [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nextjs-build-api)). When I call `next start` and then load a page that uses SSR (by defining [getServerSideProps()](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)) then I can see in the developer console that the page that I load downloads resources that are prefixed `_next` (e.g. `<script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-3123a443c688934f.js" defer=""></script>`).

1. Can someone confirm whether the `.next` directory contents (`.next/server/**`, `.next/static/**`) are just made available on the server by being renamed to `_next`?

I tried creating a new page in a file called `_next.js` as an experiment. The project builds correctly (no errors reported and there are build artifacts created with the same naming convention as the other pages).  However, when I try to load that page, I get a 404.

2. Are there restrictions on what constitutes a validly named page in Next.js? If so, what are they and where is this defined.
3. How does the Next.js server know what is a static resource that should just be given to the client and what is a page for which Next.js should render an output? Is it simply an algorithm like "if the path starts `_next/` then return what is requested, otherwise render?"
4. How does Next.js know to distinguish between resources that are in the `public` directory and pages? e.g. if there's a collision between the name of a page and a resource in the `public` folder, how does the server know what to return to the user?

Comment: I would try to limit your question to a single problem.

Comment: To answer point 4, if you have the same name for a resource in `public` and a page in `pages` Next.js will throw an error. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/conflicting-public-file-page.